# How to read file from Azure SAS using Java

Tags: java, spring

I have SAS URL of CSV file in Azure Bolb Storage. I need to download the file and write it to a SQL database. The question is, how to download the file using SAS URL. I tried with `RestTemplate`, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException`. Since I'm new to Java I can't figure this out.

```
String url="https://orcatest.blob.core.windows.net/ABC/extract.csv?st=2020-04-";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

ResponseEntity<String[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(link, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String[].class);
```